# Is it possible to edit the web pages in the Profile Manager user portal?

Tags: macos, osx-server, server.app, profile-manager

When setting up Profile Manager in Lion Server, there are a few web pages that are generated for web management of both devices and profiles.  Is it possible to edit these pages in any way?  I am just looking to customize the look and feel without changing the functionality.

If editing is possible, where are these pages stored?  I have looked through the /Library/Server/ProfileManager and /Library/Server/Web folders without any luck.

[image: enrollment page]

This is one particular page I would like to edit. Ideally I would like to be able to edit the HTML directly.  I am looking to match the page's style with a variety of other pages hosted on the server.

Comment: Yes — it's definitely possible, although a screen capture of the page(s) you are referring to, along with how you plan to customize them might help.

Comment: I and can't verify this (since I'm on holiday), but try looking in `/usr/share/collabd/coreclient/public/`. Another thought I have is if you're using Firefox you could use the Web Developer function or the Firebug extension to examine the origins of everything on the page you're interested in possibly customizing.

Comment: @ioi There wasn't anything relevant in the `/usr/share/collabd/coreclient/public/` directory.  I am not super familiar with Firebug, but it will likely only give relative origins.  Giving the exact origin would be a security issue as you shouldn't be able to see the exact source of files on a web server through a browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to locate the source for these pages.  The comments on this question by [ioi's](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/10139/ioi) were leading in the right direction.  The root directory for the app is `/usr/share/devicemgr/`.  The portal is actually a Ruby on Rails app, so there is no direct HTML to edit.  However, there are CSS files that can be edited to fit your needs.  The CSS files relating to the page I posted are located in `/usr/share/devicemgr/backend/public/start_ota/`.

Comment: glad you found it; i had a feeling there wouldn't be any actual HTML to edit — at least there's the CSS though.